# New added attribute value pass from product detail page to cart, checkout and order

Tags: magento

I have added new attributes to the product with multiselect option in admin.
I get the values for the selected attributes from checkbox in view.phtml (product page).

Now, I want to pass these selected checkbox values to the cart page, checkout page and order page. But I am struggling to find an easy way to do so.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
here available_colors is my attribute name

```
<div class="available_color span10" style="margin:10px 0;">
            <?php
            $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('available_colors')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
            $color = $_product->getAttributeText('available_colors');

            //print_r ($color);
            ?>
            <h2>Item Color</h2>
            <?php foreach ($color as $value): ?>
                <label class="span4" style="margin-left:0px;">
                <input class="pro_color_<?php echo $value; ?>" name="<?php echo $value; ?>" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" type="checkbox">
                <?php echo $value; ?>                   
                </label>                    
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
```

it display in product page but problem is that 
when I add to product add-to-cart attribute value not pass and display in cart, checkout page.

Comment: Look at how the code handles configurable products?
Also the convert line of models

Comment: but i have no configurable product i have simple product with custom attribute and add custom attribute value pass product page to cart and checkout page

Comment: have you found any solution for this

Answer (score 0):

You could use Product Custom Options to acheive this.Select the product to which you want to add custom options .You can find a tab named Custom Options.You can add the options there.

Comment: I don't want to use Custom Options as it is not user-friendly. I have already tried it but I need other option like Product attributes.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want, you need to store your product attribute through the quote and finally to the order.

You'll need to :

- create new attribute (column) on quote and order
- fill these new attributes with the user selection when adding product to quote
- display it on the checkout (quote attribute value) and on the order page (order attribute value)

For the attribute creation check this link : http://www.atwix.com/magento/custom-product-attribute-quote-order-item/ .

For the display of your attribute on your pages, you just have to adapt your code to check the quote_item or order_item values.

Comment: Don't confound product attribute and order_item and quote_item attributes. order_item and quote_item attribute are usued to persist the product attribute's value on the quote and the order. Read the link I gave you carefully.

Comment: yes Bixi I have add attribute in 
admin-->catalog-->Attributes-->Manage Attribut-->Add new attribute

and it's value can be display with check box in view.phtml using this code::

   

     $color = $_product->getAttributeText('available_colors');

<?php foreach ($color as $value): ?>
   <label class="span4" style="margin-left:0px;">
   <input class="pro_color_<?php echo $value; ?>" name="<?php echo $value; ?>" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" type="checkbox">
   <?php echo $value; ?>
   </label>
<?php endforeach; ?>
Now I wantto add Selected Checkbox Value can be pass in cart,
Checkout and order

Comment: mike please give me your email address i am sending my website url and discuss more briefly with you...

Comment: Hello Bixi My attribute is System Attribute not custom attribute than also i follow your link???
And Tell me Where is System attribute Module path in our store?????